# internal resistance of inductor effect

Tags: inductor, resistance, coil, voltage, internal-resistance

I'm trying to analyze an RL Circuit .

I saw this equation for voltage drop over an inductor:

```
V = L * di/dt
```

But what about internal resistance of the inductor ?

I have a coil that have about 2 ohms resistance. how can I use this equation for it ? can I assume the internal resistance as a resistor before or after the coil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coil is series combination of an inductor and a resistor so voltage drop across coil would be V = L * di/dt +iR

can I assume the internal resistance as a resistor before or after the coil ?

I think you meant to say before or after the inductor , it doesn't matter in which order you model inductor and resistor(in series) voltage drop would be same

Comment: thank you . so you mean I can assume the internal resistance of the coil as a resistor in series with it ?

Comment: Yes you got that!